# Good YAML code isn't accepted by Bukkit

Tags: yaml, bukkit

So I have the YAML code that I made for [PermissionsBukkit](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permbukkit/) 1.6.

But that stopped working with the new Minecraft update.
The [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) couldn't find any issues with it.

```
users:
Grace:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
cracksmacker141:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
msymons:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - default
chris:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
humptyP:
    permissions:
    groups:
    - admin
Msaltafosso:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
        jcommands.clear: true
    groups:
    - admin
SgtCookie23:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
        war.zonemaker: true
        war.player: true
        jcommands.back: true
    groups:
    - admin
Binglee2323:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - admin
Bscott:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
Mac:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
Cole:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
        BlockControl.lava: true
        BlockControl.fire: true
    groups:
    - mod
Dan:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
dr_michael4:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
Dunny:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
fnaty:
    permissions:
    permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
doldfield:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
Gunpowderjr:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
mwa_haha:
    permissions:
        jcommands.gamemode: true
        jcommands.day: true
        jcommands.night: true
        jcommands.sun: true
        jcommands.storm: true
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
Sweet_Lemonade2:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
tdrive:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
Tppskid:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - mod
Tswizzle:
    permissions:
        permissions.example:true
    groups:
    - user
mypettr0ll:
    permissions:
        permissions.example:true
    groups:
    - user
confessor:
    groups:
    - user
l3thalxpredator:
    groups:
    - user
l3thalxshredder:
    groups:
    - user
wack-a-mole:
    groups:
    - User
Jaffa117:
    groups:
    - User
jmz01:
    groups:
    - user
groups:
    default:
        permissions:
            permissions.build: false
    mod:
        permissions:
            jcommands.spawn:true
            jcommands.setspawn:true
            war.zonemaker:true
            war.player:true
            jcommands.back:true
            jcommands.day:true
            jcommands.night:true
            jcommands.sun:true
            jcommands.tp:true
            jcommands.tphere:true
            jcommands.kick:true
            permissions.build:true
            simpleprefix.admin:true
            jcommands.kill:true
            jcommands.tp2p:true
            jcommands.storm:true
            jcommands.ram:true
            jcommands.ping:true
            jcommands.gamemode:true
            jcommands.broadcast:true
    admin:
        permissions:
            jcommands.afk:true
            jcommands.spawn:true
            jcommands.setspawn:true
            jcommands.mute:true
            jcommands.heal:true
            jcommands.gamemode:true
            permissions.build:true
            simpleprefix.admin:true
            jcommands.tp2p:true
            jcommands.storm:true
            jcommands.ram:true
            jcommands.ping:true
            jcommands.invisible:true
            jcommands.ip:true
        inheritance:
        - mod
    user:
        permissions:
            jcommands.afk:true
            permissions.build:true
            jcommands.home:true
            jcommands.spawn:true
            jcommands.sethome:true
            lockette.user.create.*:true
            jcommands.ram:true
            jcommands.ping:true
messages:
    build: '&cUser Error.'
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check all your indentations.

For the user `fnaty` the permission was not indented correctly.

```
fnaty:
    permissions:
    permissions.example: true  <-- This line should be indented.
    groups:
    - user
```

Should be like this:

```
fnaty:
    permissions:
        permissions.example: true
    groups:
    - user
```

For user `humptyP` you have a `null` value for their permissions. While this is acceptable for YAML, Bukkit tends to not like this practice and may throw errors.

```
humptyP:
    permissions:  <-- Add a permission or remove this line.
    groups:
    - admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything under `users:` should be indented once. At the moment users has no childs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have indented everything correctly. If you used tabs for some things and spaces for others it will not work. Also, remake a smaller file with one group and one user and see if you can get that working.